# org.springframework.web.multipart.MultipartException

Tags: javascript, java, spring, model-view-controller

File is uploading with below stack trace.
Currently using spring 3.2

I have added maxsize limit in bean. But getting same error

org.springframework.web.multipart.MultipartException: Could not parse multipart servlet request; nested exception is org.apache.commons.fileupload.FileUploadException: Async IO operation failed (1), reason: RC: 55  The specified network resource or device is no longer available.

```
at org.springframework.web.multipart.commons.CommonsMultipartResolver.parseRequest(CommonsMultipartResolver.java:163)
at org.springframework.web.multipart.commons.CommonsMultipartResolver.resolveMultipart(CommonsMultipartResolver.java:139)
at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.checkMultipart(DispatcherServlet.java:1056)
at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doDispatch(DispatcherServlet.java:902)
at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doService(DispatcherServlet.java:867)
at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.processRequest(FrameworkServlet.java:953)
... 26 more
```

Caused by: org.apache.commons.fileupload.FileUploadException: Async IO operation failed (1), reason: RC: 55  The specified network resource or device is no longer available.

```
at org.apache.commons.fileupload.FileUploadBase.parseRequest(FileUploadBase.java:362)
at org.apache.commons.fileupload.servlet.ServletFileUpload.parseRequest(ServletFileUpload.java:115)
at org.springframework.web.multipart.commons.CommonsMultipartResolver.parseRequest(CommonsMultipartResolver.java:156)
... 31 more
```

Caused by: java.io.IOException: Async IO operation failed (1), reason: RC: 55  The specified network resource or device is no longer available.

```
at com.ibm.io.async.AsyncLibrary$IOExceptionCache.<init>(AsyncLibrary.java:891)
at com.ibm.io.async.AsyncLibrary$IOExceptionCache.get(AsyncLibrary.java:904)
at com.ibm.io.async.AsyncLibrary.getIOException(AsyncLibrary.java:918)
at com.ibm.io.async.AbstractAsyncChannel.multiIO(AbstractAsyncChannel.java:482)
at com.ibm.io.async.AsyncSocketChannelHelper.read(AsyncSocketChannelHelper.java:217)
at com.ibm.ws.tcp.channel.impl.AioSocketIOChannel.readAIOSync(AioSocketIOChannel.java:206)
at com.ibm.ws.tcp.channel.impl.AioTCPReadRequestContextImpl.processSyncReadRequest(AioTCPReadRequestContextImpl.java:184)
at com.ibm.ws.tcp.channel.impl.TCPReadRequestContextImpl.read(TCPReadRequestContextImpl.java:111)
at com.ibm.ws.http.channel.impl.HttpServiceContextImpl.fillABuffer(HttpServiceContextImpl.java:4212)
at com.ibm.ws.http.channel.impl.HttpServiceContextImpl.readSingleBlock(HttpServiceContextImpl.java:3440)
at com.ibm.ws.http.channel.impl.HttpServiceContextImpl.readBodyBuffer(HttpServiceContextImpl.java:3546)
at com.ibm.ws.http.channel.inbound.impl.HttpInboundServiceContextImpl.getRequestBodyBuffer(HttpInboundServiceContextImpl.java:1813)
at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.channel.WCCByteBufferInputStream.bufferIsGood(WCCByteBufferInputStream.java:371)
at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.channel.WCCByteBufferInputStream.read(WCCByteBufferInputStream.java:265)
at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.srt.http.HttpInputStream.read(HttpInputStream.java:322)
at java.io.FilterInputStream.read(FilterInputStream.java:144)
at org.apache.commons.fileupload.util.LimitedInputStream.read(LimitedInputStream.java:134)
at org.apache.commons.fileupload.MultipartStream$ItemInputStream.makeAvailable(MultipartStream.java:999)
at org.apache.commons.fileupload.MultipartStream$ItemInputStream.read(MultipartStream.java:903)
at java.io.InputStream.read(InputStream.java:113)
at org.apache.commons.fileupload.util.Streams.copy(Streams.java:100)
at org.apache.commons.fileupload.util.Streams.copy(Streams.java:70)
at org.apache.commons.fileupload.MultipartStream.readBodyData(MultipartStream.java:593)
at org.apache.commons.fileupload.MultipartStream.discardBodyData(MultipartStream.java:617)
at org.apache.commons.fileupload.MultipartStream.skipPreamble(MultipartStream.java:634)
at org.apache.commons.fileupload.FileUploadBase$FileItemIteratorImpl.findNextItem(FileUploadBase.java:1023)
at org.apache.commons.fileupload.FileUploadBase$FileItemIteratorImpl.<init>(FileUploadBase.java:1003)
at org.apache.commons.fileupload.FileUploadBase.getItemIterator(FileUploadBase.java:310)
at org.apache.commons.fileupload.FileUploadBase.parseRequest(FileUploadBase.java:334)
... 33 more
```

[6/19/18 15:57:41:777 IST] 00000077 webapp        E com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.webapp.WebApp logServletError SRVE0293E: [Servlet Error]-[BaseControler]: org.springframework.web.multipart.MultipartException: Could not parse multipart servlet request; nested exception is org.apache.commons.fileupload.FileUploadException: Async IO operation failed (1), reason: RC: 55  The specified network resource or device is no longer available.

```
at org.springframework.web.multipart.commons.CommonsMultipartResolver.parseRequest(CommonsMultipartResolver.java:163)
at org.springframework.web.multipart.commons.CommonsMultipartResolver.resolveMultipart(CommonsMultipartResolver.java:139)
at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.checkMultipart(DispatcherServlet.java:1056)
at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doDispatch(DispatcherServlet.java:902)
at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doService(DispatcherServlet.java:867)
at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.processRequest(FrameworkServlet.java:953)
at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.doPost(FrameworkServlet.java:855)
at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:595)
at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.service(FrameworkServlet.java:829)
at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:668)
at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.servlet.ServletWrapper.service(ServletWrapper.java:1227)
at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.servlet.ServletWrapper.handleRequest(ServletWrapper.java:776)
at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.servlet.ServletWrapper.handleRequest(ServletWrapper.java:458)
at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.servlet.ServletWrapperImpl.handleRequest(ServletWrapperImpl.java:178)
at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.filter.WebAppFilterManager.invokeFilters(WebAppFilterManager.java:1032)
at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.webapp.WebApp.handleRequest(WebApp.java:3761)
at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.webapp.WebGroup.handleRequest(WebGroup.java:304)
at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.WebContainer.handleRequest(WebContainer.java:976)
at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.WSWebContainer.handleRequest(WSWebContainer.java:1662)
at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.channel.WCChannelLink.ready(WCChannelLink.java:200)
at com.ibm.ws.http.channel.inbound.impl.HttpInboundLink.handleDiscrimination(HttpInboundLink.java:459)
at com.ibm.ws.http.channel.inbound.impl.HttpInboundLink.handleNewRequest(HttpInboundLink.java:526)
at com.ibm.ws.http.channel.inbound.impl.HttpInboundLink.processRequest(HttpInboundLink.java:312)
at com.ibm.ws.http.channel.inbound.impl.HttpICLReadCallback.complete(HttpICLReadCallback.java:88)
at com.ibm.ws.tcp.channel.impl.AioReadCompletionListener.futureCompleted(AioReadCompletionListener.java:175)
at com.ibm.io.async.AbstractAsyncFuture.invokeCallback(AbstractAsyncFuture.java:217)
at com.ibm.io.async.AsyncChannelFuture.fireCompletionActions(AsyncChannelFuture.java:161)
at com.ibm.io.async.AsyncFuture.completed(AsyncFuture.java:138)
at com.ibm.io.async.ResultHandler.complete(ResultHandler.java:204)
at com.ibm.io.async.ResultHandler.runEventProcessingLoop(ResultHandler.java:775)
at com.ibm.io.async.ResultHandler$2.run(ResultHandler.java:905)
at com.ibm.ws.util.ThreadPool$Worker.run(ThreadPool.java:1862)
```

Caused by: org.apache.commons.fileupload.FileUploadException: Async IO operation failed (1), reason: RC: 55  The specified network resource or device is no longer available.

```
at org.apache.commons.fileupload.FileUploadBase.parseRequest(FileUploadBase.java:362)
at org.apache.commons.fileupload.servlet.ServletFileUpload.parseRequest(ServletFileUpload.java:115)
at org.springframework.web.multipart.commons.CommonsMultipartResolver.parseRequest(CommonsMultipartResolver.java:156)
... 31 more
```

Comment: Unrelated, I was just writing that comment before you deleted your answer: When answering low quality questions, you want to make up for that in your answer. Posting a **unformatted** code only question ... is exactly the opposite of that. So please: dont just drop random code somewhere. That will not help your reputation a bit

Answer (score 0):

Fixed

Error occurred from JavaScript which was submitting twice